# How to reload current page with updated query string and disable cache with javascript?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm building a search results page. Inside this page, when I trigger a re-search, it sends an ajax call and returns a search result id, once front end has this id returned, it will trigger a redirect with the following code:

```
window.location.href = '/results/?search_results_id=' + search_results_id;
```

Where basically it's doing a page reload with an updated search_results_id. But for some reason it's not always doing a reload, sometimes it refreshes the whole page with the updated results but sometimes it's reloading the old results.

In short, the flow of the re-search is, send an ajax call to the backend with search params, backend connects with a third party api to grab the results, stored in memcache, and returns a cache id to frontend, when loading the search results page, the app uses the cache id from the url to load data from memcache and returns to front end for displaying.

My problems is when the search is triggered from the search results page, this essentially will be a page reload with an updated search result id on the url. And when it reloads, browser is loading the cached page with no request being sent to backend for new results.

Comment: Do you really need to reload the page? Can't you just use data returned by the ajax request instead? Anyway, you need to provide more context about your snippet and debug it on your side, e.g, checking if its a server side issue or client side one

Comment: When it reloads the page with old results, is it using the new `search_results_id` or does that not update?

Comment: @Xenyal I've checked the url, id is updated, but the page is the cached version

Comment: Which seems like no request is being sent